# How to handle mysql_connect error in xml using php

Tags: php

I trying to check login credential via xml using php,Following is the piece of code to check DB connection

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("<result><message>Could not connect to host</message></result>");
```

if connection fails throws error like

```
 "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://test.study.com/test/services/checkLogindata.php
Line Number 2, Column 1: ...."
```

[image]

I dont want that message,i want to display simply like ,

```
<result>
<message>Could not connect to host</message>
</result>
```

Is it possible to display like above, if yes kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found one solution by giving "error_reporting(0);" before mysql_connect();

Answer (score 0):

you should add xml header line like this

```
<?xml encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0"?>
```

Try this

```
die("<?xml encoding='ISO-8859-1' version='1.0' ?>
      <result><message>Could not connect to host</message></result>");
```

Comment: @Dinesh: What it says? Is there any error? I think that could be seen using view source

Comment: @Shakthi Actually by viewing source, message is coming, but its not shown in page

Comment: @Dinesh: xml will not shown directly on your browser. You needs to store xml data into file.

Comment: @Shakthi updated my post now Taken that screen shot in Firefox

Comment: @Shakthi Finally i found one solution by giving "error_reporting(0);" before mysql_connect(); Thanks for your support